# how to use json in ruby interactive console?

Tags: ruby, json

my application uses json-1.6.1 which works fine, also I can do "gem install json" from command line w/o a problem.

when I open the interactive console and type "require 'json'" I get an error "no such file to load -- json (LoadError)". I use windows.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
```